# HashMap in service method of servlet

Tags: java, servlets, collections, hashmap, thread-safety

If a `HashMap` is created under the service method of the servlet than will it be thread safe? 
It is a user based web-application, different users will login and access the servlet and hence access their specific map data according to their groups.

```
service(request,response) { 
  HashMap h = new HashMap();
  h.put(keyfromserver,valuefromserver);   // this is in for loop
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code to propose your design.

Comment: please see the sample code

Comment: It is thread safe, but the `map` would be lost unless it is saved into session scope or somewhere else.

Comment: okay , but saving it in session scope will also be thread safe right ? I will do something like this ... session.setAttribute("map",h); and get the map in different servlet . So doing this will also be thread safe ?

Comment: Yes, it will be thread safe.

Comment: Your code won't compile (your `service()` method lacks a signature).  Additionally, your `HashMap` is a raw type, you should use generics and specify what types of keys and values the map should hold.  Finally, your sample doesn't indicate what you do with the map, nor if it's stored anywhere.  Certainly, if you create a `HashMap` inside a method, populate it, and are done with it, as you describe here, you will run into no thread-safety concerns, but you'll also have not actually used your map.  Please update your code with a more realistic example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @dimo414 it is just a sample...

Comment: If it's an incomplete, non-compiling sample, it's rather difficult to determine how the proposed code would behave when actually implemented.

Comment: @ Thanks Luiggi.It helps alot...one more question to you different from this .I am using this map in differnt servlet where i am having two boxes left and right. Left box will display the different values with check box and simillarly rightbox will display the different values with checkboxes. so user will check the values in the left box and move those to the right. ( continued in second comment ).

Comment: simillarly he can move some values back to the Left box. I am using jQuery for this. so i want to understand if i am following the right path here.....so what is happening is when user check values in left box and click on >>(right arrow) it will call some servlet and update those values send the response back to the jsp and display. Is this the right approach ?  this is breaiking my head for long and you seems an expet to me..

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You made a claim.  There's no telling if your claim is correct or not, because there's no telling what the final code is going to do.

Comment: once the hashmap store all the values for the user , the user can edit those values and submit again , this is all the final code will do. like user may add new keyFromserver to his hashmap and may reduce some valuefromserver in the existing keys of the map...

Comment: @dimo414 the only way to make this unsafe for multi threading is if defining the map as a field in the Servlet class. But the map is defined inside `service` method, so its behavior would be thread safe. That's the problem at hand, and that's how it will be handled.

Answer (score 1):

If such object is created in the service method of a servlet, and supposing the `service` method make this object available to the programmer through other methods like `doGet` or `doPost` by putting the map in the request or the response objects, this object still would be thread-safe, because it was created during a request execution and the service method serving just a particular thread.

If other request, in another thread was made, it would imply another invocation of the service method, and therefore it would instantiate another map object.

You would make the use of the object unsafe if you would keep a reference of it outside the scope of a given request, like keeping it in a static field or saving it into shared session. In whose case, the object use is not limited to a request, but to multiple other requests, possibly happening in different threads.

Comment: what do you mean by shared session ? i have to use session.setattribute("map",h) in first servlet and than need to get that session.getattribute("map") in second servlet ....

Comment: so you mean session.setattribute("map",h)  will not be thread safe ?

Comment: I think every user session will be different and hence there sud not be any issues of thread conflict ? only thing i can think of is if the same user will try to use the application in the multiple tabs of the same browser ?